# Xamarin.Forms: Binding to Entire BindingConext in C# (not XAML)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

The syntax to bind an item to the entire `BindingContext` in XAML is `{Binding .}`.

How do I do the same in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# equivalent is to `{Binding .}` is to omit the Binding Path, e.g. `.Bind(Button.CommandParameter)`

### XAML Example

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter ="{Binding .}"
```

### Code Example

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;

// ...

new Button().Bind(Button.CommandProperty, "ButtonCommand").Bind(Button.CommandParameterProperty)
```